# How to target specific rows for replacement with order is different between dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have 2 dataframes that I want to fillna with but the order is not the exact same, is it possible to target specific columns as part of the mapping?

Here's a example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2016', '2016', '2015', '2014', '2013'],
        'country':['uk', 'usa', 'fr','fr','uk'],
        'rep': ['john', 'john', 'claire', 'kyle','kyle']
        })

dataNew = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2016', '2016', '2015', '2013', '2014'],
        'country':['usa', 'uk', 'fr','uk','fr'],
        'sales': [21,10, 20, 12,10],
        'rep': [np.nan, 'john', np.nan, np.nan, 'kyle']
        })

print(data)
print(dataNew)
print(dataNew.fillna(data))
```

My output is not right because if you see, dataframe new's country data is not in the same order(uk/us are shifted and so is fr/uk at the end).  Is there a way to match it based on year, country and sales before replacing the NaN value in the rep column?

The output I'm looking for is, like the first data column. I'm trying to understand how I could have filled in the NA's by selecting a matching cells in another df. To make the question easier I made the first data column have less fields so the question is purely about mapping/searching

```
   year country  sales     rep
0  2016      uk     10    john
1  2016     usa     21    john
2  2015      fr     20  claire
3  2014      fr     10    kyle
4  2013      uk     12    kyle
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas no, I do not have that column. I'm wondering if I can match based on multiple columns not one.

Comment: @Roy2012 I'll update with that info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2016', '2016', '2015', '2014', '2013'],
        'country':['uk', 'usa', 'fr','fr','uk'],
        'sales': [10, 21, 20, 10,12],
        'rep': ['john', 'john', 'claire', 'kyle','kyle']
        })

dataNew = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2016', '2016', '2015', '2013', '2014'],
        'country':['usa', 'uk', 'fr','uk','fr'],
        'sales': [21,10, 20, 12,10],
        'rep': [np.nan, 'john', np.nan, np.nan, 'kyle']
        })

# join on these three columns and get the rep column from other dataframe
cols = ['year', 'country', 'sales']
dataNew = dataNew.drop('rep', 1).join(data.set_index(cols), on = cols)
print(data)
```

**output:**

```
   year country  sales     rep
0  2016      uk     10    john
1  2016     usa     21    john
2  2015      fr     20  claire
3  2014      fr     10    kyle
4  2013      uk     12    kyle
```

Comment: is it better to fillna vs drop? Interesting approach.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this on my problem and got this error - ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(listed my columns)...can you explain your command more?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Multi-Index along with fillna():

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2016', '2016', '2015', '2014', '2013'],
        'country':['uk', 'usa', 'fr','fr','uk'],
        'rep': ['john', 'john', 'claire', 'kyle','kyle']
        })

dataNew = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2016', '2016', '2015', '2013', '2014'],
        'country':['usa', 'uk', 'fr','uk','fr'],
        'sales': [21,10, 20, 12,10],
        'rep': [np.nan, 'john', np.nan, np.nan, 'kyle']
        })

(dataNew.set_index(['year', 'country']).sort_index().fillna(
    data.set_index(['year', 'country']).sort_index())
).reset_index()

   year country  sales     rep
0  2013      uk     12    kyle
1  2014      fr     10    kyle
2  2015      fr     20  claire
3  2016      uk     10    john
4  2016     usa     21    john
```

Comment: HI there, I got this error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Comment: Hi, I pasted in the full code block.  I tested in a Jupyter notebook (after re-starting the kernel).  I have Python 3.8; pandas 1.0.5; and NumPy 1.18.5.  But this should not be an issue if you have different versions.